# Build and export tables using "struct2table" function

Tags: database, matlab, struct, append

I would like to build a table in "ascii" format, using the "struct2table" function. When printed into a cell my structure as the following characteristics:

> report.COUNTRY.SOURCE.SCENARIO.CATEGORY.ENTITY = YEAR YEAR

Therefore in order to use the "struct2table" function I wrote a script that loops over field names as follow:

```
function comboloop = loopover(myStruct)

country=fieldnames(myStruct);
for countryidx=1:length(country)
    countryname=country{countryidx};
    source=fieldnames(myStruct.(countryname))    
    for sourceidx=1:length(source)
        sourcename=source{sourceidx};
        scenario=fieldnames(myStruct.(countryname).(sourcename))        
        for scenarioidx=1:length(scenario)
            scenarioname=scenario{scenarioidx};
            category=fieldnames(myStruct.(countryname).(sourcename).(scenarioname))            
            for categoryidx=1:length(category)
                categoryname=category{categoryidx};
                struct2table(myStruct.(countryname).(sourcename).(scenarioname).(categoryname))
            end
        end
    end
end
end
```

Then, I have two problem with the output:

- The output is printed directly on the command window, therefore how can I get an output as a table (ascii) in the workspace or outside matlab?
  When I use `table=struct2table(myStruct.(countryname).(sourcename).(scenarioname).(categoryname))` I get the error message "too many output arguments".
- How can I append the results of the line `category=fieldnames(myStruct.(countryname).(sourcename).(scenarioname))`as a row header of the created output?

Any kind of helps or hints is greatly appreciated since I am struggling quiet a lot for this task!

As an example:

- country = HUN
- countryname = HUN
- source = CRF2014
- sourcename = CRF2014
- scenario = BASEYEAR
- scenarioname = BASEYEAR
- category = CAT0 CAT1 CAT2 CAT3
- categoryname = CAT0 CAT1 CAT2 CAT3
- when running the struct2table, for each categoryname I have several gas entities as a column header (CO2, CH4, N2,...) and below I have the attached years (1990, 1991, 1992,...)

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example that everybody can run, containing only one or two for loops?

Comment: @Ihcgeneva - I would be pleased to provide example! But unfortunately I have no idea about how to attached files!

Comment: Just define your example structure in the code, the simpler the better.

Comment: @Ihcgeneva - a brief minimal example of the structure has been added (hope this might be clearer now)

Comment: A minimal example is a thing that's runnable (can't run your above example :P) and MINIMAL, meaning one or two fields of your category, just to be able to get a proof of principle. There's no use in nesting four for-loops if you cannot print the result even in the simplest case ;)

Comment: @Ihcgeneva - sorry I will try to rearrange that!